# iPad Native crashes when app resumes back

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, native-code

The iPad app crashes when we idle the app for sometime and then resume it from the lock state, the crash log is shown below the app freezes and to restrat the app we need to do the soft reset to the app

```
    Incident Identifier: EDF8518C-EFE6-4E99-B462-B5FD7BC4C68C
CrashReporter Key:   59b53e06d0757c3331182b9eed3d03b9bc5194d4
Hardware Model:      iPad2,1
Process:             ll [2353]
Path: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CCD700F0-DDC1-4E4A-AC23-B424866AD7DF/ll.app/ll
Identifier:          com.sw.ll
Version:             0.5.1 (0.5.1)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-05-27 14:19:32.184 +0530
Launch Time:         2015-05-27 13:49:22.619 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F69)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xbbadbeef
Triggered by Thread:  4

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a38849c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a388290 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2ba577ee __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2ba55db4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2b9a199c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2b9a17ae CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   GraphicsServices                0x331221a4 GSEventRunModal + 132
7   UIKit                           0x2f12c690 UIApplicationMain + 1436
8   ll                              0x000e6e3a 0xb3000 + 212538
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x3a2d5aac start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a38824c kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a2a84ec _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 276
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a2a821e _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 34

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a38849c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a388290 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2ba577ee __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2ba55db4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2b9a199c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2b9a17ae CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   CFNetwork                       0x2b53f642 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 482
7   Foundation                      0x2c7d0186 __NSThread__main__ + 1114
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a41bde8 _pthread_body + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a41bd5a _pthread_start + 114
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a419b04 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a38849c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a388290 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2ba577ee __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2ba55db4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2b9a199c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2b9eb366 CFRunLoopRun + 94
6   CoreMotion                      0x2c2b6ab6 0x2c271000 + 285366
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a41bde8 _pthread_body + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a41bd5a _pthread_start + 114
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3a419b04 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4 Crashed:
0   JavaScriptCore                  0x2cf99286 WTFCrash + 54
1   JavaScriptCore                  0x2cedca80 JSC::JSLock::DropAllLocks::DropAllLocks(JSC::VM*) + 176
2   WebCore                         0x375fec7c SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*) + 180
3   WebKitLegacy                    0x3811c42a CallResourceLoadDelegate(objc_object* (*)(objc_object*, objc_selector*, ...), WebView*, objc_selector, objc_object*, objc_object*, objc_object*) + 206
4   WebKitLegacy                    0x381036b6 WebFrameLoaderClient::dispatchDidFailLoading(WebCore::DocumentLoader*, unsigned long, WebCore::ResourceError const&) + 202
5   WebCore                         0x3762c5e2 WebCore::ResourceLoadNotifier::didFailToLoad(WebCore::ResourceLoader*, WebCore::ResourceError const&) + 62
6   WebCore                         0x3762bf44 WebCore::ResourceLoader::cancel(WebCore::ResourceError const&) + 316
7   WebCore                         0x3762bdf2 WebCore::ResourceLoader::cancel() + 50
8   WebCore                         0x375a753e WebCore::CachedResource::removeClient(WebCore::CachedResourceClient*) + 390
9   WebCore                         0x37f8badc WebCore::WebCoreAVFResourceLoader::invalidate() + 24
10  WebCore                         0x37cf45a2 WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateAVFoundationObjC::~MediaPlayerPrivateAVFoundationObjC() + 262
11  WebCore                         0x37cf4ce0 WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateAVFoundationObjC::~MediaPlayerPrivateAVFoundationObjC() + 4
12  WebCore                         0x37cf00ca WebCore::MediaPlayer::~MediaPlayer() + 110
13  WebCore                         0x37cf010c WebCore::MediaPlayer::~MediaPlayer() + 4
14  WebCore                         0x3798ba8e WebCore::HTMLMediaElement::~HTMLMediaElement() + 842
15  WebCore                         0x3796f9d8 WebCore::HTMLAudioElement::~HTMLAudioElement() + 4
16  WebCore                         0x37cd96a4 WebCore::LiveNodeList::~LiveNodeList() + 40
17  WebCore                         0x37f2c54e WebCore::CachedLiveNodeList<WebCore::HTMLTagNodeList>::~CachedLiveNodeList() + 138
18  WebCore                         0x3768f00e WebCore::HTMLTagNodeList::~HTMLTagNodeList() + 78
19  WebCore                         0x3768eb28 WebCore::JSNodeListOwner::finalize(JSC::Handle<JSC::Unknown>, void*) + 276
20  JavaScriptCore                  0x2cd1f654 JSC::WeakBlock::sweep() + 72
21  JavaScriptCore                  0x2ccbe7f0 JSC::WeakSet::sweep() + 16
22  JavaScriptCore                  0x2ccbe79a JSC::MarkedBlock::sweep(JSC::MarkedBlock::SweepMode) + 14
23  JavaScriptCore                  0x2cf25dd0 JSC::MarkedAllocator::tryAllocateHelper(unsigned long) + 128
24  JavaScriptCore                  0x2ccbdfee JSC::MarkedAllocator::allocateSlowCase(unsigned long) + 114
```

I'm uploading the screen where the break point will be paused

[image]

Comment: you still have problem ?

Comment: yes we still have the problem. thanks for the immediate reply

Comment: can u upload the code on github ? maybe I can help u ?

Comment: have added a screen shot in the question, see if that can help

Comment: performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone will fix it

Comment: this is a multi-thread issue , you create the WebView from thread 1, then you trying  to modify its contents by means of JS functions in thread 2 ???

Comment: this line of snippet "performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone " where to embed it ?

Comment: you should read how to use multithreading, how do threads interact. After that, it will be clear where to place that function. :) Or, you can post your code so we can solve it together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79493/discussion-between-omarj-and-chetan).

Answer (score 1):

This is an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` type of code which relates to accessing `deallocated` memory. In order to find this you need to enable `NSZombie` objects. Press `Option/alt + Command + R` and select the "`Diagnostics`" tab. Finally, click "`Enable Zombie Objects`". This should make the compiler stop on the line of code that is causing this crash.

[Apple documents about Application with Diagnostics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDiagnostics.html)
[image]